# How to access to FlowSaveTrigger?

Tags: visual-workflow, automation

I couldn't delete flow version because it's referenced in  **Flow Save trigger** ;

[image]

and i couldn't navigate to this section ;

[image]

The flow isn't referenced in Paused interview neither in Fails interviews - but i couldn't find the reason ..

Comment: What's the URL for this page? That might help us tell you how to fix this.

Comment: *https://*******.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/42C1q0000004STnEAM/view*

Comment: its a FlowSaveTrigger , but i dunno where i can find it

Comment: This might involve a call to support. I see FlowSaveTrigger is not API accessible, either Tooling API or REST API, and I can't get a describe from it in any tool, including Apex. It's also undocumented, as far as I can tell.